# Shiny - inputText renderText with trema / diaeresis

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny seems to handle text with a diaeresis incorrect due to an encoding issue.
I've tried adding `options(encoding="UTF-8")` but no improvement.

For example: i type ë and it shows Î, but in the logfile it show {"char":"Ã«"}

I hope someone stumbled on the same issue.

Reproducible example which handles text as input.

```
options(shiny.trace = TRUE) # Print debugging info to console
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Test input characters"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("char", "Write character", "")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({ input$char })
  }
))
```

sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Shiny_0.7.0 and using chrome

** Shiny trace **

```
Listening on port 8100
SEND {
 "config": {
 "workerId": "",
"sessionId": "b32ed6dc994bd484ab4a39cae0903c79" 
} 
}
RECV {"method":"init","data":{"char":"",".clientdata_pixelratio":1,".clientdata_url_protocol":"http:",".clientdata_url_hostname":"localhost",".clientdata_url_port":"8100",".clientdata_url_pathname":"/",".clientdata_url_search":"",".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":true}}
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"char":"Ã«"}}
```

**Update** exploring the app on my mac, and it has no encoding issues.

Comment: I get the same log as yours, but the character rendering is correct in the app. Firstly update to shiny8, but I'm not sure this is the cause.

Comment: updated to shiny8, but no improvement on my windows machine. however, i dont face this issue on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. You have to change the encoding from `UTF-8` to `latin1`.

```
library(shiny)

options(shiny.trace = TRUE) # Print debugging info to console
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Test input characters"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("char", "Write character", "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("dsI")  
    )   
  ),   
  server = function(input, output) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({ aaa=input$char 
    iconv(aaa, "UTF-8", "latin1") })
    output$dsI<-datasetInput  
  } 
))
```

Hope it works fine!